# Asignación columna dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un diccionario "tempLocs" que tiene una key que como value tiene otro diccionario. Quiero iterar en un df y dependiendo de la key coordinates para cada iteración, guardará un resultado en la nueva columna, previamente "declarada".

Aunque me resulta bien, me parece una forma fea de hacerlo. ¿Se os ocurre alguna forma más elegante? Incluso sin el for....

```py
df['newCol'] = ""

for i in range(len(df)):
  coordinates = df['tupleLocation'][i]
  df['newCol'][i] = tempLocs[coordinates][0]['key1']`
```

Gracias y saludos

Comment: Podrías usar e método `apply` aunque creo que tendrá que hacer el llamado a una función

Comment: Algo del estilo de `df["newCol"] = df.tupleLocation.apply(lambda x: tempLocs[x][0]['key1'])`